# What is the purpose of IEnumerator

Tags: c#

Hi all i searched for IEnumerator but could not get to understand it.it would be great help if anyone helps me.

basically trying to understand the its role in this code

```
string requestUriString = URL;
if (requestUriString.IndexOf("http://", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) < 0)
{
    requestUriString = "http://" + requestUriString;
}
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestUriString);
try
{
    IEnumerator enumerator;
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
    string sSourceString = reader.ReadToEnd();
    reader.Close();
    string str6 = this.funcParseStringFromString2String(sSourceString, "<div class=\"title\">", "<div class=\"searches_related\">", false);
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    list = this.funcParseStringFromString2Stringx(str6, "<h3><a ", "</h3>", false);
    int num = this.DataGridView2.RowCount + 1;
    try
    {
        enumerator = list.GetEnumerator();
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            string str8 = Conversions.ToString(enumerator.Current);
            string str7 = this.funcParseStringFromString2String(str8, "title=\"", "\" href=", false);
            string str5 = this.funcParseStringFromString2String(str8, "\" href=\"", "\">", false).Replace("\" class=\"rated", "");
            this.DataGridView2.Rows.Add(new string[] { Conversions.ToString(num), Conversions.ToString(false), str7, str5 });
            this.lblInsProg.Text = "Done: " + Conversions.ToString(this.DataGridView2.Rows.Count) + " Articles found";
            num++;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (enumerator is IDisposable)
        {
            (enumerator as IDisposable).Dispose();
        }
    }
    if (list.Count == 0)
    {
        this.lblInsProg.Text = "No results found for " + this.search.Text + "!";
        this.Button11.Enabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        this.Button11.Enabled = true;
    }
    if (this.DataGridView2.RowCount != 0)
    {
        this.Button15.Visible = true;
    }
    return Conversions.ToString(0);
}
catch (WebException exception1)
{
    ProjectData.SetProjectError(exception1);
    WebException exception = exception1;
    ProjectData.ClearProjectError();
}
return Conversions.ToString(0);
```

Comment: I really hope that's not a code that you consider as something good and worth learning from.

Comment: yes that is some ........ code

Comment: I see that it is some ....... *code*. I am just hoping that it is not some code that you are using, writing, trying to learn from or ever putting in production (that would be considered as crime). That's all. Just expressing a concern. Believe me, it's for your own good :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This part of the code:

```
try
{
    enumerator = list.GetEnumerator();
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        string str8 = Conversions.ToString(enumerator.Current);
        //...
    }
}
finally
{
    if (enumerator is IDisposable)
    {
        (enumerator as IDisposable).Dispose();
    }
}
```

is basically the same as:

```
foreach(var value in list)
{
    string str8 = Conversions.ToString(value);
    //...
}
```

but the latter is far more readable, don't you think ?

Answer (score 4):

`IEnumerator` allows you to iterate over a list, array, etc. (anything that implements `IEnumerable`) and process each element one-by-one.

If you're familiar with a `foreach` loop in C#, `IEnumerator` is what it uses under the covers. For example, this:

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>() { "one", "two", "three" };

foreach(string elem in myList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(elem);
}
```

Is actually translated to something like this:

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>() { "one", "two", "three" };

IEnumerator<string> enumerator = list.GetEnumerator();

while(enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    string elem = enumerator.Current;

    Console.WriteLine(elem);
}
```

(This is simplified, as there are other cleanup operations that `foreach` does, like disposing the enumerator if it implements `IDisposable`, but this addresses the relevant portion)

In fact, your entire `try-finally` code block is almost a dead-on copy of how the `foreach` construct gets translated into IL.

Answer (score 1):

The IEnumerator interface allows the `while()` {} part of the code to loop through `list` one by one with the MoveNext() method.

It is the C# "iterator"-pattern implementation.  Any class that implemented the interface IEnumerator can be iterated over.  Often it is used with the [foreach syntactic sugar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6%28VS.80%29.aspx?ppud=4).

It's a somewhat sloppy way of writing it.  The try/finally is not really necessary.  I would expect that section of the code to look like this:

```
var list = new ArrayList(); // (or a newer, generic container, like List<T>)
...
foreach (var item in list)
{
    string str8 = Conversions.ToString(item);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an Iterator. As far as I know it follow the [Iterator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator_pattern)

Answer (score 0):

I would read Jon Skeet's book C# in depth, it is the best explanation of this I have seen although the version of the book I am referring to is 3 and the version that is out now is 4 - I don't know if it is covered the same in that version...

This is not as in-depth as the book but this is useful... 
http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/csharp2/iterators.html